# Server management using PHP

Tags: java, php

I have a Java server application. I Also have a PHP page which displays logs related to the server, both the page and the server share the same database. I want to be able to stop/start the server (which starts from a .bat) through my page.

What is the best and most secure way to accomplish this?

I tried using some functions which are supposed to run files like `exec` and `system` but they just didn't work. I think it's because these are disabled on XAMPP.

Obs.: I can't kill the server process, it would left the ports in use.

Comment: `exec` isn't disabled on XAMPP, but check if safemode is enabled because that would prevent exec from working. In that case you'd have to use `safe_mode_exec_dir` (if you're using PHP 5.4.0 safemode won't be the issue, since it was removed). 

Also, have you tried running the shutdown command via the command line? (Just to be sure that it works). If you're on windows, be sure to escape all backslashes in any paths that are part of the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java-based server should expose some kind of admin interface, for example a socket or a Web Service. When it receives a message (which meaning is "shutdown") it starts an orderly shutdown.

As a security measure, the admin interface should only listen on `127.0.0.1`.